# jQuery-bootgrid how to hide column only in Mobile and Tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, jquery-bootgrid

I would like to hide the data column in Tab.
I referred [Bootgrid Documentation](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation).

In Column setting I found.

```
data-visible="false"
```

It hides the data column in PC also. I need something like

```
 .hidden-xs, .hidden-sm
```

Comment: Have you tried using media query like `@media screen and (max-width : 320px){  display: none; } `

Comment: I added the css class to the '@media screen and (max-width : 320px){ .data-column{ display: none; } }' It hides only the column header not entire column

Comment: Can post the code/fiddle of your problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two column settings called `cssClass` and `headerCssClass` which do exactly what you ask. If you set `hidden-xs` and `hidden-sm` classes inside the column header data attributes, that column will be hidden on small devices. Note that data attributes are called **`data-css-class`** and **`data-header-css-class`** respectively.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-column-id="id" data-visible="false">ID</th>
        <th data-column-id="firstname">First Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="lastname" data-order="asc">Last Name</th>
        <th data-column-id="registerdate" 
            data-css-class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" 
            data-header-css-class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```